# Error while adding an image in FlowDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, image, flowdocument

I'm using this code to add an image into a FlowDocument

`doc.Blocks.Add(new BlockUIContainer(image));`

However, I get this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'

How do I add an image into a FlowDocument?

Answer (score 1):

Add full absolute to your resource like this:

```
var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/(your project name);component/Resources/PangoIcon.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

...and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `System.Windows.Controls.Image` and not `System.Drawing.Image`.

You can use this bit of code to convert your `Drawing.Image` to `Controls.Image`

```
public static BitmapImage ToWpfImage(this System.Drawing.Image img)
{
  MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream();  // no using here! BitmapImage will dispose the stream after loading
  img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

  BitmapImage bitMapImage = new BitmapImage();
  bitMapImage.BeginInit();
  bitMapImage.CacheOption=BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
  bitMapImage.StreamSource=ms;
  bitMapImage.EndInit();
  return bitMapImage;
}
```

Comment: I get the same error when I add a BitmapImage as an argument.

Comment: When i add the System.Windows.Controls.Image, I get an saying "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first." I don't want to disconnect the image.

Comment: @Vinshi You don't want to add the `Image` that has a `Parent` to another object. You have to disconnect it. One way is to just create a new `Image` with the copied `source`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` you have to put a WPF `System.Windows.Controls.Image` control into the BlockUIContainer. First, you have to convert your `Bitmap` into something that can by used as the `Source` of an `Image` e.g. a WPF `BitmapImage`. Then you would create a new `Image` control and add that to your document:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = ...
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
}

var image = new Image
{
    Source = bitmapImage,
    Stretch = Stretch.None
};

doc.Blocks.Add(new BlockUIContainer(image));
```